# What should I expect when I have read only data in my react component using react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a component which contains only text without any mock calls or buttons or textfields. the read only text comes from another component through props. What should I expect for that component in the code here `expect(container).`?

Code:

```
import React from "react";

export default function BasicTable(props) {
const rows = props;

return (
<div>
  {rows.map((row) => (
    <div>{row.calories}d</div>
  ))}
</div>
);
}
```

Test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import BasicTable from '../BasicTable';

beforeEach(() =>
{
window.scrollTo = jest.fn();
window.HTMLDivElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = jest.fn();
});

describe('Read only text', () => {

 const rows = [{calories: 13, fat: 200}, {calories: 15, fat: 230}]

it('text came from props', () => {
    const { container } = render(<BasicTable rows={rows} />);
    expect(container).
});
});
```

Comment: Your expectation is that text gets rendered, so maybe `expect(container.textContent).to...` or if you're using `jest-dom/extend-expect` you can use [`.toHaveTextContent`](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavetextcontent) on the container itself.

Comment: An error is coming while using  toHaveTextContent which is   'property toHaveTextContent does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<HTMLElements>' '

Comment: And *have* you included `@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect` anywhere? That looks like a TypeScript error but you don't seem to be writing TypeScript, nothing's typed.

Answer (score 1):

You can test, i.e, either the component **renders correctly** and has **correct text**, something like:

```
describe('BasicTable', () => {
  const mockedRowsProp = [{ calories: 13, fat: 200 }, { calories: 15, fat: 230 }]
 
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    render(<BasicTable rows={mockedRowsProp} />);
  });

  it('has correct calories', () => {
    render(<BasicTable rows={mockedRowsProp} />);
    expect(screen.getByText(/13/)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText(/15/)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```